# WPF Binding external styles with no XAML tag

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

If I have a WPF DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridQ" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f3f" />                                   
        </Style> 
    </DataGrid.Resources>   

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name2" Binding="{Binding Name2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And If I wanted to style the DataGrid from an external style sheet and bind the style to the grid, I write the style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="DataGridstyle">
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF636363" />       
</Style>
```

and bind it like this:

```
<DataGrid {StaticResource DataGridstyle}" />
```

And that's fine, but if I wanted to bind to the DataGrid's rows I don't actually have a tag in the above XAML to create a binding, therefore having to do the style in the `<DataGrid.Resources>` within the grid. Is it possible to create a binding to the external style resource, despite not having a XAML tag for the DataGrid row?

**EDIT**: Idea of what I'm going for:

```
 <DataGridRow {StaticResource DataGridRowstyle}" />
```

But this isn't possible because the rows are created from the binding within DataGrid Column. So there is no 'data grid row' tag for me to attached a style binding to

Comment: Explain with some example code/markup what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp10.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>

        <x:Array x:Key="array1" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>Row 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Row 2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Row 3</sys:String>
        </x:Array>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f3f" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridQ" 
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource array1}" 
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle1}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name2" Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MergedDictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    ... <Some other resources> ...
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Grid.Resources>
```

MyResourceDictionary can look like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Style TargetType="..." BasedOn="...">
   ...
  </Style>
   ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```